# Is there a basic class for sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a basic routine that does some page formatting stuff (set headers and footers and so on). This routine has the sheet as the first parameter:

```
Sub FormatSheet(Optional ws As Worksheet = Nothing, _
            Optional language As String = "Deutsch", _
            ...)
```

All worked fine until today someone had a workbook with a `Chart`-sheet. As you can set all the properties also for such a sheet, I said to myself *"fine, no problem, I will change the parameter type to `Sheet` instead of `Worksheet` - problem solved*. However, I couldn't find any such `Sheet`-class.

My workaround was to change the parameter type to `Object` - this works. However, I don't like this attempt too much as an Object can be anything and I want to explicitly allow only - uuhm *Sheets*. Of course, I can solve this by checking the Object type and whatnot, but my basic question is: Is there any "parent" class type in Excel/VBA for any Sheet?

Comment: Nope. Use Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no common object in the heirarchy of Excel.Chart and Excel.Workhseet. So, in taking the parameter, you will need to take it as an Object in the sub signature. But, if you really don't like the generic object in your code, you could add a segment that will classify the input object into either a worksheet or chart.

```
Sub FormatSheet(Optional obj As Object = Nothing, _
            Optional language As String = "Deutsch", ...)

    Select Case TypeName(obj)
        Case "Worksheet"
            Dim ws As Worksheet

        Case "Chart"
            Dim cht As Chart

        Case Else

    End Select
    Set ws = obj '//work with this throughout your code.


End Sub
```

You'll want to make sure that whatever your code does with the ws object is valid for charts AND worksheets. Otherwise, you need to handle each case in a logical branch.

Comment: `If TypeOf obj Is Excel.Worksheet` / `If TypeOf obj Is Excel.Chart` would be more type-safe than `TypeName`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I expected. As I said, my routine works with the `Object`-attempt, I just don't like the fact that I have to program something to check if the type is valid - I think that's the job of the compiler.

Comment: @FunThomas - its a downside to VBA that you can't overload functions. That's basically how you'd handle this in any other langague. :-/

Comment: @FunThomas the compiler is doing its job perfectly well. The lack of a common interface between `Chart` and `Worksheet` isn't a VBA problem, it's an Excel Object Model problem. The problem is that you haven't told us much about *what is it that you need to do with a chart or worksheet*. Maybe a `PageSetup` object would be a better suited type to use. Principle of least knowledge applies to every language, even those that support method overloading.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: I perfectly understand that the compiler does it's job and that we are talking about a problem with the Object Model . Anyway, you nailed it with your suggestion - I can use a `PageSetup`-Object for my purposes.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't, because there is no need for one.

If the purpose of `FormatSheet` is to configure the sheet's `PageSetup`, then take a `PageSetup` argument instead of the whole `Worksheet`.

The `Chart` class, like `Worksheet`, has a `PageSetup` property of type `PageSetup`.

c.f. [Principle of Least Knowledge / Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter): give a procedure as little as it needs to do its job. You don't need a whole `Worksheet` to configure `PageSetup`.

Comment: As always - well said! You should probably mark this as the accepted answer instead of mine.

Comment: @ArcherBird to be fair your answer *is* the most common, general-purpose solution, and whether taking a `PageSetup` parameter works depends on exactly what's going on in `FormatSheet` -- and the code isn't in the OP, so that was basically a stab in the dark, based on the very slim details in the OP and assuming the procedure adhered to the Single Responsibility Principle, something that is far from being a given in typical VBA code.

Comment: I mean, I'll take the reputation :-D. This is off topic so I'll probably remove this comment in a second, but just want to say thank you for Rubberduck. I use it literally every day!